# Defining JPA repositories in test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-test

I created some library with aspect which works with JPA repositories. What I am trying to achieve is to create tests for that particular aspect. There are neither repositories nor entities in source code of the library. So in test I need to test this aspect inside of spring context with test entities and repositories. So in test sources I defined DataJpaTest with properties to enable in-memory h2 and jpa ddl create, an entity class and repository interface which derives from CrudRepository. By starting of test I see JPA saying after scanning that 0 repositories found.

I have tried to add repository class into context configuration annotation, then in enable JPA repositories, used also entity scan. Nothing works and I understand that what can be is that probably either repositories and entities scan generally disabled in test classes or there is some kind of other trick which I do not know yet. Does enybody tackled already such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

have you mentioned the annotations in their respective places?

like this

**entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "demoEntity")
public class  DemoEntity{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

//attributes

//methods / getters & setters

}
```

then repository

```
@Repository
public interface DemoEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<DemoEntity, Intiger>{
    
    
}
```

hopefully, then it should work else you can ping me any time, I'm always here.

and please provide some sample code or error pages for better understanding.

Comment: Yes sure. All the same, just entity classes and repository interface are in src/test/java - so they are available only in test. So in test sources I have one entity, one repository for the entity, in properties I am setting embedded h2 and also point to the entity and repository with all possible matters like component scan, entity scan enable repositories. Embedded database starts, but context sees no repositories after scan :(

Comment: `Starting TestClient using Java 17.0.4.1 on T000becfae with PID 94351 (started by 

The following 1 profile is active: "test"

Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.

Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
`

Comment: @DmitriZamysloff can I see your code, please